# CouchDB deleted database shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration-management, diskmanagement, couchdb, sharding

Currently running clustered CouchDB v3.1.1 on an AWS EC2 Instance

q=2
n=3

Number of Nodes: 1

I have moved the database directory to another drive on my VM. But can't find any on the documents regarding the files under **/var/lib/couchdb/shards** or **.shards** growing big consuming my root directory. Under **/var/lib/couchdb/shards** on one folder of 3 shards I have found that there were multiple files that are large mostly from the deleted database(s).

```
68M  database1.1610087019.20210108.074010.deleted.couch
60M  database12.1610091614.20210108.082256.deleted.couch
309M database13.1610094180.20210302.091450.deleted.couch
61M  database1.1614676497.20210302.095632.deleted.couch
271M database12.1614678996.20210303.013757.deleted.couch
270M database13.1614735481.20210303.074912.deleted.couch
279M database13.1614757800.20210308.064857.deleted.couch
40M  database12.1615186143.20210308.065855.deleted.couch
```

Does this have to be removed manually? I ran compaction on the said database(s) but no change on the disk size.

Answer (score 0):

The .deleted.couch files on shards folder can be manually deleted as these were part of the **database_recovery** config on Couch.